# SSRS 2016 Custom Authentication error - ProcessingObjectModel DLL access denied

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016, reporting-services-2016

We have two instances of SSRS 2016 installed, as one of them requires Windows authentication and the other requires custom authentication. The latter follows all the latest direction from the sample everyone references, except that it leverages a REST call to a separate authentication API we use for our applications rather than creating a user DB just for this use. We have given ourselves all permissions via the web portal, using the user account from this separate authentication API. Everything works fine until we finally try to execute a report and receive the error,

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

We've found nothing referencing such an error and are stumped at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Content when viewing Page Source of error page:  "The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file."  However, the SSRS web.config includes the suggested fix exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I had ran into this exactly same issue, and the cause was permissions setup for the execution account. I was providing him with admin permissions and full control setups on the folder, and file but the issue persisted. The solution was to remote desktop on the machine with the execution user account and acess the REport Server bin folder. With this the pop up to gain permanent admin permissions on it showed, and accepting this lifted the issue.
It took me days to nail this down, which seems like a bug. so I thought of posting this. I hope this helps.